# How to handle OpenCL code on unsupported hardware in a C++ app

Tags: opencl

I've been doing some research in to OpenCL, and the possibility of using it on a project. The question I have is, is there a way to run OpenCL code on a CPU that is unsupported by the OpenCL SDKs in a C++ application. I know Java has Aparapi, however I'm wondering how to run OpenCL code in a C++ application without hardware that is supported by the SDKs. There is some code I would like to write in OpenCL kernels to take advantage of the OpenCL parallelism where available, however I'm unsure if I wouldn't be able to run it on older hardware (still X86, but not recent hardware). Could anyone explain to me how this can be done, or if it is even a problem at all to run OpenCL code on older systems?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say best way to approach this is to check if the device supports OpenCL via OpenCL API calls such as clPlatformIDs then once you figure it isn't a OpenCL device then run the required code as normal C/C++ function otherwise run it using openCL kernel. But for portability you need to write the program logic twice once in .cl file and once as normal c/c++ method/function.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, it would be nice if there was a way to run OpenCL on unsupported hardware on native, but I guess that isn't possible.